# Doubly linked list FM station implementation

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, doubly-linked-list

The Question is:

Create a bidirectional linked list of FM stations (mentioned below) using C. Then set pointer to first station.
Take user input:
Enter 1 to play next station
Enter 2 to play previous station
Enter 3 to play first station
Enter 4 to exit

The linked list for FM station related data should be:

Station 1          Radio_City             91.1
Station 2          Radio_One             91.8
Station 3          BIG_FM                  92.7
Station 4          RED_FM                 93.5
Station 5          My_FM                   94.3
Station 6          Hit_FM                    95.0
Station 7          Radio_Mirchi          98.3
Station 8          Vividh_Bharti          100.1
Station 9          Gyan_Vani               105.6
Station 10        Radio_Dhamal        106.4
Station 11        DD_News                108.2
Station 12        Gyan_Ganga           109.6

The code that I have written is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    int sno;
    char sname[50];
    float sfreq;
    struct Node *Lnext,*Rnext;
};

struct Node *createnewnode()
{
    int n;
    struct Node *first,*last;
    printf("\n Enter the number of stations available:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    first=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    printf("\nEnter the Station number: ");
    scanf("%d",&first->sno);
    printf("Enter the Station Name: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",first->sname);
    printf("Enter the station Frequency: ");
    scanf("%f",&first->sfreq);
    last=first;
    last->Lnext=NULL;
    last->Rnext=NULL;
  
    int i=2;
    while(i<=n)
    {
        struct Node *temp=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        printf("\nEnter the Station number: ");
        scanf("%d",&temp->sno);
        printf("Enter the station name: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s",temp->sname);
        printf("Enter the station frequency: ");
        scanf("%f",&temp->sfreq);
        
        temp->Lnext=last;
        last->Rnext=temp;
        last=last->Rnext;
        last->Rnext=NULL;
        
        i++;
    }
    return first;
}

void display_by_position(struct Node *first)
{
    struct Node *temp=first;
    printf("\n The list of stations is....\n");
    if(temp==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nThere are no stations to display");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n\tSTATION NUMBER\t\tSTATION NAME\t\tSTATION FREQUENCY");
        for(temp=first;temp!=NULL;temp=temp->Rnext)
        {
            printf("\n\t%d\t\t\t%s\t\t\t%.1f",temp->sno,temp->sname,temp->sfreq);
        }
    }
    
    int choice;
    while(choice!=4)
    {
        printf("\n-------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("\nEnter \"1\" to play the next station");
        printf("\nEnter \"2\" to play the previous station");
        printf("\nEnter \"3\" to play the first station");
        printf("\nEnter \"4\" to exit");
        printf("\n-------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("\nEnter your choice: ");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        
        if(choice==1)
        {
            if(temp->Rnext==NULL)
            printf("\nThis is the last station\n");
            else
            {
                temp=temp->Rnext;
                printf("\n The next station is...\n");
                printf("\nStationNumber:  %d      %s      %f\n",temp->sno,temp->sname,temp->sfreq);
            }
        }
        
        else if(choice==2)
        {
            if(temp->Lnext==NULL)
            printf("\nThe is the first station");
            else
            {
                temp=temp->Lnext;
                printf(" \n The previous station is...\n");
                printf("\nStationNumber:  %d      %s      %f\n",temp->sno,temp->sname,temp->sfreq);
            }
        }
        
        else if(choice==3)
        {
            temp=first;
            printf("\n The first station in the list is...\n");
            printf("\nStationNumber:  %d      %s      %f\n",temp->sno,temp->sname,temp->sfreq);
        }
        
        else if(choice==4)
        {
            printf("\n Thank you for your patience...");
        }
        
        else
        {
            printf("\n Invalid choice...");
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct Node *p=createnewnode();
    display_by_position(p);
    return 0;
}
```

In this code, the program gets terminated when the user gives input as '1' to play the next station. Similarly, the program gets terminated for whatever input the user gives

Comment: Two things: First of all passing an input-only stream (like `stdin`) to `fflush` is explicitly mentioned in the C specification to lead to *undefined behavior*. Please unlearn that bad habit. Secondly, I suggest you try to separate the functions you have. Like instead of one single function that both creates node, read input, and add nodes to the list, I suggest you create one function that create nodes, one that reads input and initializes a *single* node, one function that inserts nodes into a list (passed as an argument). Then one function to call these functions in a loop.

Comment: On another note, in C you don't have to, and really shouldn't, [cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). And don't `#include` headers that aren't needed, especially if they're non-stanmdard (like the `<conio.h>` header).

Comment: And lastly for your "termination" problem, it's very likely a *crash*. And you start solving crashes by learning how to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your programs. For example by using a *debugger* to catch the crash when it happens, and locate where in your code it happens. Then you can also examine variables and their values.

Comment: Unrelated: `int choice;  while (choice != 4)` Um.. feeling lucky? Initialize `choice` to literally anything-not-4. Don't leave it up to tempting fate.

Answer (score 0):

While you initialize `temp` with `struct Node *temp=first;`, you subsequently use `temp` as a loop variable to show the list of stations:

```
               for(temp=first;temp!=NULL;temp=temp->Rnext)
                  {
                          printf("\n\t%d\t\t\t%s\t\t\t%.1f",temp->sno,temp->sname,temp->sfreq);
                  }
```

which means that `temp == NULL` when the loop exits.  When you subsequently press '1' it does `temp->Rnext` which will dereference a NULL pointer and your program crashes.

You have to be really careful when reusing variables like this, so it's usually much safer to create a local variable when needed:

```
               for(struct Node *temp=first;temp!=NULL;temp=temp->Rnext)
                  {
                          printf("\n\t%d\t\t\t%s\t\t\t%.1f",temp->sno,temp->sname,temp->sfreq);
                  }
```

You should move `struct Node *temp=first;` to before your `choice`-loop, say, after `int choice;` otherwise your compiler might complain that  variable is being shadowed.

Breaking your program into smaller functions will also help you isolate parts of your program so you only have to reason about each part instead of the entire program all at once.  For example you could extract the list of stations like this:

```
int list(struct Node *first) {
    printf("\n The list of stations is....\n");
    if(!first) {
        printf("\nThere are no stations to display");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("\n\tSTATION NUMBER\t\tSTATION NAME\t\tSTATION FREQUENCY");
    for(struct Node *t=first; t!=NULL; t=t->Rnext) {
        printf("\n\t%d\t\t\t%s\t\t\t%.1f", t->sno, t->sname, t->sfreq);
    }
    return 0;
}

void display_by_position(struct Node *first) {
    if(list(first))
       return;
    ...
}
```

Change your `while(choice != 4) { ... }` to a `do { ... } while(choice != 4)` so you are not checking the value of an uninitialized variable.

You are repeating yourself in `createnewnode()` so is my suggestion to streamline it:

```
struct Node *createnewnode() {
    int n;
    printf("\n Enter the number of stations available:");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    struct Node *first = NULL;
    struct Node *last = NULL;
    while(n-- > 0) {
        struct Node *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        if(!temp) {
            printf("malloc failed\n");
            return NULL;
        }

        printf("\nEnter the Station number: ");
        scanf("%d", &temp->sno);

        printf("Enter the station name: ");
        scanf("%49s", temp->sname);

        printf("Enter the station frequency: ");
        scanf("%f", &temp->sfreq);

        temp->Lnext = last ? last : NULL;
        temp->Rnext = NULL;

        if(!first) first = temp;

        if(last) last->Rnext = temp;
        last = temp;
    }
    return first;
}
```

You may want to check the return code of scanf, for example, if you enter "a" for station number it will not work the way you expect: